# Isn't the blockchain size going to be a huge problem in the future?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ethereum-classic

At the moment the blockchain is already quite large. And since the main idea behind the blockchain technology is to get away from services that provide the information and rather have the information on different nodes around the web, isn't this going to be a problem in the future?
Imagine Ethereum will be as successful as predicted and nearly everyone uses it. The size of the blockchain will then probably exceed terabytes pretty soon, which means that you have to use centralized services to provide functionality. Or am I completely wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

We already have "blocks full" problem and gas price going up for Ethereum mainnet.

The long term solution for this problem [sharding](https://near.org/blog/the-authoritative-guide-to-blockchain-sharding-part-1/). In a sharded chains, all validators do not need to validate and store all blocks. The downside is that the mechanism for such blockchains is at least one order of magnitude more complex than naive single shard proof-of-work chain.